# How to Subscribe to Sync Gateway using RESTFul API in Java for 'GET /{db}/_changes'?

Tags: java, synchronization, couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

Connect to Sync Gateway using Stand alone Java program/Spring FrameWork, RESTFul API in Java for `GET /{db}/_changes`

Comment: Yes, sure, indeed

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  What exactly do you need to know?  Have you tried anything?